# registration system error with input

Tags: java, android

Unfortunately, I do not understand the problem with this part of my code.
I'm setting up a registration system.
It seems to be wrong when recording correct information.

```
   if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() &&
        !(name.length() < 4) && !(password.length()<5)  && email.lastIndexOf(".") - email.indexOf("@") > 2 &&
                email.contains(".") &&  email.lastIndexOf("@") < email.lastIndexOf(".")
                 && email.contains("@")  ) {
            registerUser(name, email, password);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Something is Wrong! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
```

please, help me to edit this. thank you

Comment: did you checked what is wrong with your code ? either your password is invalid or it can be name or email ?

Comment: Use proper email validation. Try this:

public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches());
}

Comment: I think maybe, my connection has a problem because everything is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of messing up your validation do a neat check. Either use this email validation

```
 public static boolean isValidEmaillId(String email){

    return Pattern.compile("^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$").matcher(email).matches();
}
```

**Or** this one:

```
  public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

and then do your validation like this:

```
 if (!name.isEmpty() && !name.length() < 4) && (!password.isEmpty() &&!(password.length()<5))  && isValidEmail(emailId)) {
        registerUser(name, email, password);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Something is Wrong! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: @umair it will be isValidEmail(emailId) instead of !isValidEmail(emailId). You forgot to remove the ! (not).

Answer (score 3):

Use this to validate emails:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches()); }
```

It is possible that your email validation is wrong here.

Your final code snippet:

```
if (!name.isEmpty() && !name.length() < 4) && (!password.isEmpty() &&!(password.length()<5))  && isValidEmail(emailId)) {
    registerUser(name, email, password);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Something is Wrong! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: thank you, Be sure to do your advice ... thank you again